# Stripe payment error (You must supply either a card or a customer id) using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use the stripe to make a small payment form in my application using Laravel. I followed even the tutorials from Laracast. I'm getting this error

```
Stripe_InvalidRequestError 
You must supply either a card or a customer id
```

.

```
//billing.js
(function(){

    var StripeBilling = {

        init: function(){
            this.form=$('#billing-form');
            this.submitButton = this.form.find('input[type=submit]');
            this.submitButtonValue = this.submitButton.val();

            var stripeKey=$('meta[name="publishable-key"]').attr('content');

            Stripe.setPublishableKey(stripeKey);

            this.bindEvents();
        },

        bindEvents: function(){
            this.form.on('submit', $.proxy(this.sendToken, this));
        },

        sendToken: function(event){
            this.submitButton.val('One Moment').prop('disabled', true);
            Stripe.createToken(this.form, $.proxy(this.stripeResponseHandler, this) );

            event.preventDefault();

        },

        stripeResponseHandler: function(status, response){
            if(response.error){
                this.form.find('.payment-errors').show().text(response.error.message);
                return this.submitButton.prop('disabled', false).val(this.submitButtonValue);
            }


            $('<div>', {
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'stripe-token',
                value: response.id
            }).appendTo(this.form);

            this.form[0].submit();
        }
    };

    StripeBilling.init();

})();
```

.

```
//StripeBilling.php

<?php
namespace Acme\Billing;

use Stripe;
use Stripe_Charge;
use Config;

class StripeBilling implements BillingInterface {
    public function __construct()
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.secrete_key'));
    }
    public function charge(array $data)
    {
        try
        {
            return Stripe_Charge::create([
                'amount' => 1000, // $10
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'description' => $data['email'],
                'card'=>$data['token']
            ]);
        }
        catch(Stripe_CardError $e)
        {
           dd('Card was declined');
        }
    }
}
```

What might be the problem? I even took the same code from the github but same error. Everything is same as that of the Laracast. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2:** you have used `secrete_key` in `Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.secrete_key'))` - should it be `secret_key` ?

**Edit 1:** the only difference between your billing.js and laracasts' is a space between the two closing brackets at the end of `Stripe.createToken`:

```
Stripe.createToken(this.form, $.proxy(this.stripeResponseHandler, this) );
```

Assuming this doesn't solve it, have you tried created a Stripe customer ahead of processing the charge? I have a similar system (from the same Laracast) and it first creates a customer:

```
public function createStripeCustomer($email, $token)
{
    $key = Config::get('stripe.secret');

    Stripe::setApiKey($key);

    $customer = Stripe::customers()->create([
        'card' => $token,
        'email' => $email,
        'description' => 'desc'
    ]);
    // error checking

    return $customer['id'];
```

You want to be returning the customer id, which you then use in the `Stripe_Charge` array:

```
return Stripe_Charge::create(
        [
            'amount' => 1000, // $10
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'customer' => $customer['id'],
            'description' => $data['email'],
            'card'=>$data['token']
        ]);
```